Bcryptjs.compare always returning false in React App
I am having trouble with Bcrypjs.compare() when run on a handle submit of a login form. The form is created using formik.
As the code below displays, when submitting username and passkey, it first finds the user in the databass, along with the stored hashed passkey and then also the stored salt.
The stored salt is used in the handlesubmit to hash the passkey input from the form before using bcrypt.compare() to compare the hashed input and the stored hashed passkey.
I console log both parts and recieve an identical code in each cases.
However our compare method still returns false.
Any ideas on what is gong wrong?
const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0){
        alert("please fill out all fields")
        setFailedValidation(true)
    } else {
        setFailedValidation(false)
        console.log("running hansdlesubmit") //need to destructur
        const username = values.username;
        let storedUser = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/users/${username}`)
        console.log("stored user is", storedUser.data)
        const hashedPW = await bcrypt.hash(values.password, storedUser.data.salt)
        console.log(hashedPW, storedUser.data.passkey)
        bcrypt.compare(hashedPW, storedUser.data.passkey, function(err, res) {
            if (err){
              // handle error
              console.log(err)
            }
            if (res) {
              // Send JWT
              console.log("its a match")
            } else {
            console.log("did not match")
              // response is OutgoingMessage object that server response http request
            }
          });

      
      
  
    }    


To verify an existing password you don't compute the hash and then compare, instead you use the compare function with the unhashed user-provided password together with the hashed password from the database. The "hashed" password in the database actually is stored in a format that includes the algorithm parameters and the salt in addition to the hash, so it as easy and foolproof as possible.
